# How to troubleshoot bash completion for git not working in subshell

Tags: bash, autocomplete

When I launch my first bash shell, completion for git works (`git rest<TAB>`->`git restore`).
After opening a second shell within the first one, tab completion is no longer working for git, but regular file completion is still working.

The output of `completion` is the same in both shells (except sort order).

```
$ echo $0
-bash
$ complete git
$ git rest<TAB>     # <--- works
$ cd<TAB>           # <--- works
$ bash

$ echo $0
bash
$ complete git
$ git rest<TAB>     # <--- does NOT work
$ cd<TAB>           # <--- works
```

How do I figure out where it's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the subshell is not a login shell.  I noticed from the output you posted that the first shell is a login shell (because it has a '-' as the first character) and the subshell is not a login shell.

In my bash installation the `/etc/profile` script sources all of the scripts under `/etc/profile.d/`, which includes `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`.  But, bash does not read `/etc/profile` for non-login shells.  I confirmed that if I start a non-login subshell (with just `bash`) then git completions don't work, but if I then do `. /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh` they start working.

A more general workaround may be to start the subshell as a login shell using `bash --login`.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably it! And yes, the lower example is started with the command  `bash`. I can't investigate until tomorrow.